# YAML: “Unsupported parameters for ansible module"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

i get the below error when try this as below:

> "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule) module: delegate_to Supported parameters include: affinity_rule, cluster_name, drs_rule_name, enabled, hostname, mandatory, password, port, proxy_host, proxy_port, state, username, validate_certs, vms".

I dont want my module to execute when the final_list is empty or less than one object. Only if its more than 2 object in final_list i would want it to execute. Could someone help me with the correct condition

```
    "ansible_facts": {"final_list": [ "NPSY7ADFS01"]}
    "ansible_facts": {"final_list": []}

    - name: Create DRS Anti Affinity Rule for VM-VM
       vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule:
         hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
         username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
         password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
         cluster_name: "{{ datacenter_name }}-{{ cluster_name }}"
         validate_certs: no
         vms: "{{ final_list }}"
         drs_rule_name: "{{ rule_name }}"
         enabled: True
         mandatory: True
         affinity_rule: "{{ action_type }}" 
         delegate_to: localhost
       register: rule_creation
       when: final_list is defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Unsupported parameters for (vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule) module: delegate_to ... "*

A: The error message is clear: *"delegate_to is not a parameter of vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule"*. The indentation of [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) is wrong. This is the reason why `delegate_to` has been considered a parameter of the module. Fix the indentation of `delegate_to`

```
     - name: Create DRS Anti Affinity Rule for VM-VM
       vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule:
         hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
         username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
         password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
         cluster_name: "{{ datacenter_name }}-{{ cluster_name }}"
         validate_certs: no
         vms: "{{ final_list }}"
         drs_rule_name: "{{ rule_name }}"
         enabled: True
         mandatory: True
         affinity_rule: "{{ action_type }}" 
       delegate_to: localhost
       register: rule_creation
       when: final_list is defined
```

FWIW. Use [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) to validate the syntax.

---

> Q: *"I don't want the module to execute when the final_list is empty."*

A: Try this

```
       when: final_list|default([])|length > 0
```